# Custom Post Type shows pagination (w/404) or posts_per_page query, but not both

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination, pre-get-posts, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type of `gallery`, and I'm using a template for the archive of `page-student-gallery.php`. My admin settings for posts shown is 5, I'd like it to show 9 on this page which only contains gallery items.

I've been able to manage the query where it can show EITHER 9 posts OR 5 posts with pagination at the bottom, which leads to a 404 error. I've been checking out code for doing this, but everyone seems to have a different way of going about fixing the problem, and none of the solutions are working for me.

My code for the archive page:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'paged' => $paged
   //'posts_per_page' => 9
));           
while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<article class="oneThird gallery">...</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<ul class="pcount">
    <?php wp_pagenavi();
      wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

My attempts at using `pre_get_posts`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'show_more_posts');
function show_more_posts($query){
    if($query->is_post_type_archive('gallery') && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() )
       $query->set('post_type', 'gallery');
       $query->set('posts_per_page', '9');
};
```

I'm really confused at this point. What is the best way to implement this kind of setup?

Comment: You cannot have a post type called gallery.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'm finding a lot of other users are registering custom post types called 'gallery', and they're working. Is there a source behind this?

Comment: `gallery` is used internally by WordPress. I do not say that this definitely your issue, but naming custom objects the same as internal objects can cause issues. So avoid it where you can

Comment: `is_post_type_archive` is true on a post type archive- you have a page named `student-gallery`. you also can't target a custom query with `is_main_query`, it's not the main query. is there a reason you're using a page with an extra query instead of the built in post type archive?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'm re-creating a design for a site that uses gallery as the post type and I need to use this just to transfer over the old data.

Comment: @Milo I was following Custom Post Type UI instructions but it seems it led me astray. Creating a archive-gallery with a vanilla Loop, along with removing `is_main_query` has solved all problems, and the pages now show with 9 posts and correct pagination.

Answer (score 0):

user5477769 reports in the comments of the original post, that the problem has been solved:

> I was following Custom Post Type UI instructions but it seems it led
>   me astray. Creating a `archive-gallery.php` with a vanilla Loop, along with
>   removing `is_main_query` has solved all problems, and the pages now show
>   with 9 posts and correct pagination.